# Read POST-Data from Server-Log?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, post, logging

I've got a big problem: When redirecting my website's content (from something like domain.com/sub/form.php to new-domain.com/form.php) via .htaccess I wasn't aware of losing ALL my POST-Data which was sent through a HTML-Form. Right now I'm missing like 2 months of user-input...
Is there any way to read out the server-logs to get all the submitted Form-Data which was lost because auf the .htaccess-redirect? This would be so awesome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By default, most web-servers do not log the body of post requests. That would be way too much data to deal with and store.

There are ways to do so (like turning mod_logio on for Apache) but it's for debugging / troubleshooting purposes.